# Redis timeout in cloudrun environment on load testing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-run

we are using cloudrun service with laravel. Our existing app is hosted in digitalocean services [both redis & app]. we did a load testing of 500 hits per second using digital coean and got success response. Recently we moved our service from digital ocean to google cloudrun. Cloudrun service is working fine but load testing we got redis timeout error after 120+ hits. what we tried so far ?

1. Hosted redis in digital ocean and tried with cloudrun - timeout after 100+ hits
2. Hosted redis in google managed service and tried with cloudrun - timeout after 100+ hits
3. Hosted redis in Virtual machine and tried with cloudrun. - timeout after 100+ hits
4. Hosted redis in Virtual Machine and app in Virtual Machine - **Success** no errors

I am getting timeout error only in cloudrun. did any faced this issue ? or guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Where is the virtual machine? What do the Redis logs show? There are not enough details in your question. We can only guess. Note: when using commercial well-managed services/products and I have problems, I first assume I have created the issue until I can prove otherwise. Show what you have done to configure and debug this problem.

Comment: Virtual Machine is in google premises. I deployed the service in kubernetes and we are not getting redis timeout in load testing. there must be some config I am missing in cloudrun or issue is present in cloudrun itself. 

Log was not enabled in redis, next time i will enable it and test. Thanks for your reply